# Intellisense is not working for some databases

Tags: t-sql, ssms, intellisense

When I work with different servers, some of the databases queries does not show IntelliSense. why is that?

Comment: If you are in SSMS, try Ctrl+Shift+R to Refresh the Intellisense.

Comment: @developer   I have tried it. But no luck.